# how to logout MFSideMenu

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am developing app in which i am using MFSIDEMENU for showing right hand sidebar, but this menu comes in picture after 3 screens,
First screen is login then screen 1 and screen 2 after screen 2 on screen 3 i am showing that side menu option.but now i want to give logout option also.i tried by saying pop to rootviewcontroller but it took me on that screen from which i clicked that menu. suppose i clicked that menu btn on 7th screen and traveled here and there and clicked logout button it doesn't took me to login screen.
Note: i am showing side menu option on every screen by adding following code on every screen which is maybe wrong way.
in

```
 -(void)viewdidlaod
     [self setupMenuBarButtonItems];
```

and then

```
 #pragma mark -
 #pragma mark - UIBarButtonItems

 - (void)setupMenuBarButtonItems
    {
     self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [self rightMenuBarButtonItem];
     if(self.menuContainerViewController.menuState == MFSideMenuStateClosed &&
     ![[self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0] isEqual:self]) {
     self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [self backBarButtonItem];
    } else {
    //        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [self leftMenuBarButtonItem];
    }
   }
 - (UIBarButtonItem *)rightMenuBarButtonItem {   //    menu-icon.png
    return [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
             initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@""] 
             style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered 
             target:self action:@selector(rightSideMenuButtonPressed:)];
   }

 - (UIBarButtonItem *)backBarButtonItem {
      return [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"back-arrow"]
               style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
               target:self
               action:@selector(backButtonPressed:)];
  }


 #pragma mark -
 #pragma mark - UIBarButtonItem Callbacks

 - (void)backButtonPressed:(id)sender {
      [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
 }

 - (void)leftSideMenuButtonPressed:(id)sender {
     [self.menuContainerViewController toggleLeftSideMenuCompletion:^{
     [self setupMenuBarButtonItems];
 }];
 }

 - (void)rightSideMenuButtonPressed:(id)sender {
     [self.menuContainerViewController toggleRightSideMenuCompletion:^{
     [self setupMenuBarButtonItems];
 }];
 }
```

Comment: if there is any simple way to add menu on every screen please let me knoe

Comment: can u post image of your menu??

Answer (score 0):

```
__block UINavigationController *aNv = nil;
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removeObjectForKey:@"userDetail"];
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
            if ([[AppDelegate sharedInstance].window.rootViewController isKindOfClass:[MFSideMenuContainerViewController class]]) {
                SigninVC *objSigninVC = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SigninVC"];
                aNv = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:objSigninVC];
                [AppDelegate sharedInstance].window.rootViewController = aNv;
            } else {
                [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
                [AppDelegate sharedInstance].window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;
            }
    [self.menuContainerViewController setMenuState:MFSideMenuStateClosed];
```